# How to use a recorded sound as a ringtone

Tags: iphone, audio, ringtone

How is it possible to use a sound file (recorded by the App) as a ringtone?
Can it be used in any other way out side of the Application as well?

Thanks.

Comment: This site is not for this kind of question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't programmatically change the user's ringtone.

Comment: But can I save the file so that the user will be able to manually set it as his ringtone?